# PHP - Avoid unnecessary match in preg_match

Tags: php, regex

upon using

```
\/Date\((\d{10})(\d{3})([\+\-]\d{4})?\)\/
```

on

```
/Date(1425556377427+0100)/
```

the result of `preg_match` is

```
array(
    0 => /Date(1425556377427+0100)/
    1 => 1425556377
    2 => 427
    3 => +0100
)
```

Is it possible to change the regex so it won't match the whole string as first match?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify (because that's where the -1 comes from). The regex is used in `preg_replace_callback` and thus the whole match is passed to the provided callback. That's why I would like to pass it there as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~/Date\(\K\d{10}(?=(\d{3})([-+]\d{4})\)/)~';
```

`\K` removes all on the left from the match result.
`(?=..)` is a lookahead that is not a part of the match result (its a zero-width assertion)

The idea is to use the ten digits as whole match result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to avoid matching full string here using a lookahead regex i.e.:

```
~(?=/Date\((\d{10})(\d{3})([+-]\d{4})?\)/)~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ0bU0/2)

---

**Code:**

```
preg_match('~(?=/Date\((\d{10})(\d{3})([+-]\d{4})?\)/)~', 
             '/Date(1425556377427+0100)/', $m);
unset($m[0]);
print_r($m);
Array
(
    [1] => 1425556377
    [2] => 427
    [3] => +0100
)
```

Comment: This does work, but still returns the first match. Its empty though, can that be avoided?

Comment: Check my updated code, I think this is what you need.

Comment: I sure know how unset works :) See my updated question

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible by just changing the expression.
And the reason is, as the PHP doc says:

> `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern